# How to serialize file field without host

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I have a file field:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    generated_document = models.FileField( # документ, который создала Celery из шаблона
        upload_to='generated_files/',
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    ...
```

I am serializing this field like this:

```
class DocumentSerialize(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ["generated_document", ...]
```

I want to have this `/media/generated_files/expense_contract_2022-07-17-20-02-51.pdf`

But I have result with host `http://<HOST>/media/generated_files/expense_contract_2022-07-17-20-02-51.pdf`

I know about `SerializerMethodField` but what is the proper way  to remove host in serializer?

In urls.py I am using:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(
        settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your own `FileField` and then work with that instead, so:

```
from rest_framework.fields import FileField
from rest_framework.settings import api_settings

class FileWithoutHostField(FileField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        if not value:
            return None

        use_url = getattr(self, 'use_url', api_settings.UPLOADED_FILES_USE_URL)
        if use_url:
            try:
                return value.url
            except AttributeError:
                return None
        return value.name
```

You can now inject the `FileWithoutHostField` in the [**`serializer_field_mapping`** <sup>[drf-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#serializer_field_mapping) to use this instead of the `FileField`, so:

```
from django.db.models import fields
from django_rest.serializers import ModelSerializer

ModelSerializer.serializer_field_mapping[fields.FileField] = FileWithoutHostField
```

Comment: Where (in which file) should I add ?
```ModelSerializer.serializer_field_mapping[fields.FileField] = FileWithoutHostField
 ```

Comment: Did you mean
```models.FileField``` instead of ```fields.FileField``` ?